# Can i get Field (Variable/Property) Name using Method in Java using Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

can i get Field (Variable/Property) name using method in Java using Reflection? I am explaining my scenario in following code.

for example, i have one class

```
class MyBean
{
    String name;
    String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

now i want field "Name" by using java.lang.reflect.Method "getName()"...can i get it?

i want function something like this..

```
public String getFieldName(Method method)
{
    String fieldName=null;

    // code for finding field/variable/property name using method

    return fieldName;
}
```

please help me, if possible...thanks in advance

Comment: You can't extract the field from the method. But you could take the substring of the methodname after "get".

Comment: So basically you're looking for something that removes the "get" from the beginning and turns the first character of the rest to lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

If you are naming your fields by JavaBeans convention, this should do all the thing:

```
public String getFieldName(Method method) {
    return method.getName().substring(3).toLowerCase();
}
```

So the getName() or setName() should return "name"

Comment: thank u so much but I know this answer man..but my question was how can I know that which variable ("name" or "Name") is associated with method "getName()" ??

Answer (score 0):

This works, but your class is not cleanly defined.
Fields should be named using camelCase notation starting with a lower char:

```
class Info
{
    public String name1;
    private String name2;
}
```

Now you have an object info:

```
Info info;
```

Then you want to get the value of name1:

Here is a full Test case showing all:

```
public class InfoTest extends TestCase{

public static class Info {

    private    String name1;
    public     String name2;
    protected  String name3;
    String name4;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public Info() {
        name1 = "name1Value";
        name2 = "name2Value";
        name3 = "name3Value";
        name4 = "name4Value";
    }

}

public void testReflection() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    Info info1 = new Info();

    Field[] infoFields = info1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < infoFields.length; i++) {
        Field fieldName = infoFields[i];
        System.out.println("the name of the field " + i +  ":" + fieldName.getName());
        fieldName.setAccessible(true);
        Object info1ValObj = infoFields[0].get(info1);
        System.out.println("the value of the field: " + info1ValObj.toString());
    }
}
```

}

The output then is:
the name of the field 0:name1
the value of the field: name1Value
the name of the field 1:name2
the value of the field: name1Value
the name of the field 2:name3
the value of the field: name1Value
the name of the field 3:name4
the value of the field: name1Value

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean?

```
public String getFieldName(Method method) {
    return method.getName().substring(3);
}
```

BTW: field names should be in `camcelCase` not `TitleCase`

Comment: thank u so much but I know this answer man..but my question was how can I know that which variable ("name" or "Name") is associated with method "getName()" ??

Comment: The association is via convension.  It's up to you to decide which field it should be associated with.  You can read the byte code instead but this is a) very complicated b) tricky to get right.  You could assume that since no field should be called "Name" with a capital letter it shouldn't be that one.